# Plotting an equation with constraints using sympy

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I'm currently working on a project that **requires plotting and equation with constraints** like:

`sin(x)` for `x > 1`.

but can get more complicated than this like:

`3z * cos(x)` for `x >= 0` and `x + z = 1`

I managed to take the input as a string and convert it into Sympy equations.

so far the code is like this

```py
import sympy
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

# Some other unrelated processing to the input goes here
# eventually we get a string for the equation
# and a list of strings for the constraints

equation = "sin(x)"
constraints = ["x > 1"]

x = sympy.symbols("x") 
eq = parse_expr(equation, evaluate= False)
constraints = [ parse_expr(cons, evaluate= False) for cons in constraints]
```

Now I want to plot **the given equation** with **the provided constraints**, to plot the equation for the valid constraints I tried

```py
sympy.plot_implicit(sympy.And(eq, *constraints))
```

but it doesn't work, I get an error: `TypeError: expecting bool or Boolean, not sin(x)`.

Comment: Question is too vague. Give actual code that reproduces what you see.

Comment: The rest of the code is unrelatable, I can show it but it'll make the question unnecessarily complicated. Just assume I take the equation and the constraints directly from the user through input(), it'll make no difference to the question being asked above.

Comment: If `sin(x)` is an arg to `And` which implies `y = sin(x)` then I suspect you should use something like `And(Eq(sin(x),y),x>1)`.

Comment: You really shouldn't add all your *irrelevant* code, but please add some short examples of `equation` and `cons` that do reproduce the issue.  Please add this directly into the code, not just into the text, as such can be interpreted in multiple ways.  For a clear question, that also helps you understand better what is going on, the shorter the reproducible code, the better.  Apparently, your issue can be reproduced using `sympy.plot_implicit(sympy.And(sympy.sin(x), x > 1))`

Comment: @JohanC I understand, when I posted the question I wanted a general answer that can work with multiple cases, that's why I didn't include an example code in the question, but I did add it now, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error: `TypeError: expecting bool or Boolean, not sin(x)` means that logical operators (`And`, `Or`) requires relational objects (equalities or inequalities). Instead, you provided an expression.

You have to wrap your equation into an equality:

```py
sympy.plot_implicit(sympy.And(sympy.Eq(eq, 0), *constraints))
```

EDIT: now the problem is the visualization. `plot_implicit` might be good enough to plot lines or regions, but it's definitely not good ad all at plotting "points".

For example:

```py
plot_implicit(And(Eq(sin(x), 0), x >= 0), grid=False)
```

This is good enough (albeit, the lines are very thin):
[image]

This is an example of not good enough. Note that it is able to capture the points where the expression is satisfied, but they are so small that they are almost invisible:

```py
plot_implicit(And(Eq(3*z*cos(x), 0), x >= 0, Eq(x + z, 1)), (x, -10, 10), grid=False)
```

[image]